# How to migrate from Azure SQL to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure

Okay this is not about migrating existing sql server database to azure database. Its the other way round.

I want to stop using azure sql database, and moved to full version of SQL Server. How do I migrate existing database in AZURE Sql to a new SQL Server 2008 database?

Comment: This should not be marked as a duplicate since the technology has changed significantly since the original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to lose any data, you have to stop using it for the moment of transfer. I can suggest you couple of ways:

First way is to use the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/). Yes. Although it is originally designed to migrate your local SQL DB to SQL Azure, it can be used the other way around. I've done in numerous times. Just first point the migration wizard to your SQL Azure instance, then target the local server.

Second way is to use the Azure SQL Database backup. [Create a bacpac archive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj650016.aspx#import_export) either using the portal or via SSMS. Then [import this BacPac package into your local SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710052.aspx) instance.

If you don't want downtime and want full data synchronization I will suggest doing the following:

1. Move schema and data initially using any of the above methods (for live systems I highly recommend to first a new database AS COPY and then create the BacPac from it, or use the Migration wizard to transfer it).
2. Enable the [SQL Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456371.aspx) to begin synchronizing local data with on-going live data.
3. Wait while local is fully in sync.
4. Switch the connection strings in your app.
5. Cut down SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of third party tools that will allow you to synchronize your SQL Azure database with full SQL Server database. Just use any of these to synchronize structures and then data.

You can try tools from Red Gate, ApexSQL, Idera or any other… Even though these tools are not really cheap you can still use them in trial mode (its fully functional in most cases) to get the job done.